# Is an algebraic cycle always contained some smooth ample hypersurface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective threefold over $\mathbb C$. Let $Z$ be an algebraic 1-cycle of $X$, so $Z$ consists of curves in $X$.

Is it always possible to find a smooth ample hypersurface $Y$ of $X$ containing $Z$?

In general, I wish to ask the same question for $X$ with dimension $2n-1$ and $Z$ is an $(n-1)$-cycle.

**Edited:** As Jason pointed out, this is not true when $Z$ has tangent space dimension equals to $\dim X$ at certain point.

What if we consider the rational equivalence class? Is it possible to find $Z'$ rational equivalent to $Z$ and $Z'$ is contained in some smooth ample hypersurface?

Comment: No that is not always possible.  The Zariski tangent space of $Z$ at some point might equal the entire Zariski tangent space of $X$ at that point.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks for pointing that out! I edited my question.

Comment: The answer to the edited question is yes: on a threefold, any effective 1-cycle is rationally equivalent to a smooth one.

Comment: @abx Sorry, I should have mentioned that the cycle $Z$ that I want is homologous to zero, so it is not effective. Is it still true in this case? (By the way, is there a reference for the claim for effective cycle that you mentioned?)

Comment: That the cycle is not effective dosn't matter: just write it as a difference of 2 effective cycles. For a reference, see H. Hironaka, *Smoothing of algebraic cycles of small dimension*, Amer. J. Math. 90 (1968), 1-54.

Comment: @abx Thank you very much!

Comment: You might find https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/newlefapp12.pdf interesting.

Comment: Dear @abx, thanks for the reference again! A "smooth cycle" in Hironaka's paper means an algebraic cycle $Z'$ which is a linear combination of smooth subvarieties. If these subvarieties are _disjoint_, then a version of Bertini theorem (Diaz and Harbater,
Strong Bertini theorems. Trans. Am. Math. Soc.  324, No. 1, 73-86 (1991)) would imply that there is a smooth ample hypersurface containing $Z'$. However, what if the smooth subvarieties intersect each other?

Comment: You are right, Hironaka's result is not enough. For curves in a threefold, you can use Theorem 5.8 in S.  Kleiman, *Geometry on grassmannians and applications to splitting bundles and smoothing cycles*, Pub. IHES 36 (1969), 281-297, which tells you that any 1-cycle is rationally equivalent to $Z-nL$, where $Z$ is smooth and $L$  is a section by a codimension 2 linear space (view $X$ embedded in some $\mathbb{P}^n$). A general $L$ will not intersect $Z$.